# Installing Angular 13 Server side rendering gives dependency error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, server-side-rendering

I am using `Angular ~13.3.0` and `@angular/material: ^13.3.9`

I wanted to install the Server side rendering, So I ran the command

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

getting this error.

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ava-grid@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.3.9        
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/animations@"13.3.11" from @angular/platform-browser@13.3.11    
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"13.3.11" from @angular/forms@13.3.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.3.9
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!         @angular/material@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@ctrl/ngx-codemirror, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.3.9
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)      
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @nguniversal/express-engine@"13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/animations@13.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"13.3.12" from @angular/platform-server@13.3.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-server@"^13.3.4" from @nguniversal/express-engine@13.1.1    
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine
npm ERR!       @nguniversal/express-engine@"13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have no idea what is going on here as I am using material